# How to get pushpin information inside polygon shape, in bing maps v8?

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I'm loading pushpins in map layer. Once map loaded with pushpins, using polygon am drawing a rectangle over a map. Then inside a drawn polygon i have few pushpins. I need to get pushpin information inside the polygon and store into a javascript array/object using Bing maps V8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this depend where the pushpin data is hosted. By the sound of it, in your case the pushpins are already on the map. With this in mind you can accomplish this fairly easily using the built in Spatial Math module in Bing Maps V8. Here is a code sample that shows how to do this: 
http://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#Select%20Data%20in%20Drawn%20Polygon%20Area

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. i have tried your example code, when im trying to access the pushpin information which is intersecting, am always getting the first pushpin information on all other pushpin.